# Заливка по щелчку мыши

Tags: qt

Помогите, пожалуйста. Что не так делаю?

Создал класс paintwidget наследник QWidget(сам [проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/usercoxmy00sq2w/project.rar?dl=0)). Хочу сделать простую заливку сплошной области(наподобие floodFill в делфи).

Реализовал отрисовку:

```
void PaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter pnt(this);
    QRect dirtyRect = event->rect();
    pnt.drawImage(dirtyRect, image, dirtyRect);
}

void PaintWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {

        MP1=event->pos();
        isDrawing = true;
        if (ActiveTool == 7) // если активный инструмент заливка
        {
            QColor oldClr, newClr;
            oldClr = image.pixel(MP1);
            newClr = myBrush.color();
            //Fill(oldClr, newClr, MP2);
            Fill2(oldClr.rgb(), newClr.rgb(), MP1.x(), MP1.y());
            update();

        }
    }
    event->accept();
}
```

Вот заполнение (первое заполнение взял [отсюда](http://algolist.manual.ru/graphics/fill.php#mbib4),
второе с cyberforum)

```
void PaintWidget::Fill(QColor oldClr, QColor newClr, QPoint p)
{
    QPainter pnt(&image);
    pnt.setPen(QPen(newClr));
    if( image.pixel(p) == oldClr.rgb() &&
        image.pixel(p) != newClr.rgb() )
    {
        pnt.drawPoint(p);
        Fill(oldClr,newClr,QPoint(p.x()+1,p.y()));
        Fill(oldClr,newClr,QPoint(p.x(),p.y()+1));
        Fill(oldClr,newClr,QPoint(p.x()-1,p.y()));
        Fill(oldClr,newClr,QPoint(p.x(),p.y()-1));
    }
    update();
}

void PaintWidget::Fill2(QRgb oldColor, QRgb newColor, int x, int y)
{
    if (oldColor == newColor) 
        return;

    QStack<QPoint> stk;
    QPoint pt;

    int y1;
    bool spanLeft, spanRight;

    stk.push(QPoint(x, y));

    while( !stk.empty() ) 
    {
        pt = stk.pop();
        x = pt.x();
        y = pt.y();
        y1 = y;
        while (y1 >= 0 && image.pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) 
            y1--;
        y1++;

        spanLeft = spanRight = false;
        while (y1 < image.height() && image.pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) 
        {
            image.setPixel(x, y1, newColor);
            if (!spanLeft && x > 0 && image.pixel(x-1, y1) == oldColor) {
                stk.push(QPoint(x-1, y1));
                spanLeft = true;
            } else if(spanLeft && x > 0 && image.pixel(x-1, y1) != oldColor) {
                spanLeft = false;
            }
            if (!spanRight && x < (image.width() - 1) && image.pixel(x+1, y1) == oldColor) {
                stk.push(QPoint(x+1, y1));
                spanRight = true;
            } else if(spanRight && (x < image.width() - 1) && image.pixel(x+1, y1) != oldColor) {
                spanRight = false;
            }
            y1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Заливка Fill2 работает

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос есть, тогда ответьте на свой вопрос и поставьте, что он решенный (галочка)